# Odd behaviour with <Menu> component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using a Sider component with a Menu inside which has some Submenus on it.

When my component is static, meaning not plugged to redux, just a plain component, the Menu /> and its children work as expected.

But, in my case im trying to make my menu dynamic, so in reality my component is connected to the store using Redux and to generate all the links im using mapStateToProps and then 'connect'.

When i'm using my component with Redux, for some reason the menu doesnt work as expected. The problem boils down to ANTD not removing a class, ant-menu-inline-collapsed which basically makes my the menu not show any text even when it is expanded.

To compare current behaviours vs expected, I found the ONE difference generated on the code which is basically creating the problem

Current

Closed sider:

```
<div class="ant-layout-sider ant-layout-sider-collapsed" style="..."> 
   <div class="ant-layout-sider-children">
      <ul class="ant-menu ant-menu-dark ant-menu-inline-collapsed ant-menu-root ant-menu-vertical" role="menu" ...>
```

Opened:

```
<div class="ant-layout ant-layout-has-sider"><div class="ant-layout-sider" style="...">
   <div class="ant-layout-sider-children">
      <ul class="ant-menu ant-menu-dark **ant-menu-inline-collapsed** ant-menu-root ant-menu-vertical" role="menu">
```

The problem here is that the the sider is opened, the menu UL is keeping the **ant-menu-inline-collapsed** class. In reality it should switch it to **ant-menu-inline**.

I cant understand why this is happening. As soon as i remove the redux logic from my component, the Menu behaviour works fine and the class in question is removed.

The moment i put the redux logic back in, for some reason ANTD doesnt remove said class.

I'm lost as to how to proceed.

Menu configuration is the standard and it should not be affected at all as far as i know.

This is my menu code, in case you want to have a quick look:

```
<Menu
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            theme="dark"
            mode="inline"
            defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
            selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}>
            <Menu.Item key={ROUTE_DASHBOARD}>
                <Tooltip placement="right">
                    <Link to={ROUTE_DASHBOARD}>
                        <Icon type="calendar" />
                        <span className="nav-text">Home</span>
                    </Link>
                </Tooltip>
            </Menu.Item>

            <SubMenu
                key='sub2'
                disabled={!budgetView}
                title={<span><Icon type="mail" /><span>Top Down</span></span>}>
                    <Menu.Item key="3">
                        <Link to={`${ROUTE_BUDGET}/SS/budget/${budgetId}/version/${versionName}/${versionId}/exec`}>
                            <Icon type="calendar" />
                            <span className="nav-text">Exec Recap</span>
                        </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="4">
                        <Link to={`${ROUTE_BUDGET}/SS/budget/${budgetId}/version/${versionName}/${versionId}/total`}>
                            <Icon type="calendar" />
                            <span className="nav-text">Total</span>
                        </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="5">
                        <Link to={`${ROUTE_BUDGET}/SS/budget/${budgetId}/version/${versionName}/${versionId}/women`}>
                            <Icon type="calendar" />
                            <span className="nav-text">Women</span>
                        </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="6">
                        <Link to={`${ROUTE_BUDGET}/SS/budget/${budgetId}/version/${versionName}/${versionId}/men`}>
                            <Icon type="calendar" />
                            <span className="nav-text">Men</span>
                        </Link>
                    </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
            <SubMenu
                key="sub7"
                title={<span><Icon type="team" /><span>Middle Out</span></span>}>
                <Menu.Item key="3">Option 3</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="4">Option 4</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
            <SubMenu
                key="sub3"
                title={<span><Icon type="file" /><span>Bottom Up</span></span>}
              >
                <Menu.Item key="3">Buttom Up 1</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="4">Buttom Up 2</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="5">Buttom Up 3</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>

            <SubMenu
                key="sub4"
                title={<span><Icon type="area-chart" /><span>Reporting</span></span>}>
                <Menu.Item key="3">Reporting-1</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="4">Reporting-2</Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="5">Reporting-3</Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
```

Comment: tyr to remove property defaultSelectedKeys